# Custom request queueing in WCF environment

Tags: wcf, caching, synchronization, msmq

I have following problem:

I need to synchronize access to cache objects that are accessed by WCF-service operations. The calling clients provides a parameter that maps to which cache object(s) operation will use.

In short, requests should be queued by the parameter and then executed in synchronous manner.

What would be best way to implement this? I don't want to expose the queue to the client and I want solution that easily scales if there are multiple service instance running in different machines with shared cache.